# NEED HELP WITH FINDING A KOREAN SONG

Tags: korean-culture

I heard this song in a Korean drama- prison playbook. But literally can't find it anywhere!! Googled the lyrics both in English and Korean. Even shazam didn't work! Here's the link hoping someone could help
https://youtu.be/ZHwm7WuoSrY

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8G6T2btU9Qs
It is the song of ministry of justice, "지킬수록 기분좋은 기본".

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8G6T2btU9Qs

here is the song that you are looking for. Plus, this song is CM song of Ministry of Justice.